# Infinite loop htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, loops

Im trying to make a simple html web page in 3 languages. Each language has its directory, so the index.html in "/" is in english, the spanish index in "/es" and the french index is in "/fr". Im trying to create a redirection rule for each language based on browser language or a cookie establised in the href onclick by javascript. This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*lang=ES.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept_Language} (es) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://myweb.com/es/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*lang=FR.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept_Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://myweb.com/fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* http://myweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

It is not working because a infinite loop.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that each time a user enters a page they get redirected.
e.g.: someone has a cookie that says "es" but they go to the es directory, you will still redirect them to the es page, over and over again.
You should ad a condition saying on what page each redirect should work.
something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`

edit:
Here goes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*lang=ES.*$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept_Language} (es) [AND] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^myweb.com/fr.*$ 
RewriteRule .* myweb.com/es/$1
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample code of this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Redirect loop is happening due to unconditional last rule `RewriteRule .* http://myweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. Your first 2 rules also have have an error where they are not capturing any group but using them as `$1`.

Have your rules this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*lang=ES.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept_Language} (es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!es/).*)$ http://myweb.com/es/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*lang=FR.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept_Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!fr/).*)$ http://myweb.com/fr/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!(?:es|fr)/).*)$ http://myweb.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still happening the same... infinite loop

Comment: check updated rules and make sure to test in a new browser to avoid caching issues.